# How does Canvas determine its clip bounds?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I've been doing some work with Android's `Canvas`, specifically trying to determine how its `getClipBounds` results are determined. I understand `Canvas` internally keeps a transform `Matrix` which is updated as I call `translate`, `scale`, etc. but trying to replicate that `Matrix`'s results has baffled me.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Rect clipBounds;
    RectF viewport;

    canvas.save();
    canvas.concat(translationMatrix);
    //viewportMatrix.preConcat(canvas.getMatrix());
    viewportMatrix.set(canvas.getMatrix());

    clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
    viewport = GetViewport();

    Log.d("clipBounds", clipBounds.toString() + " (" + clipBounds.width() + ", " + clipBounds.height() + ")");
    Log.d("viewport", viewport.toString() + " (" + viewport.width() + ", " + viewport.height() + ")");

    //drawing is done here

    canvas.restore();
}

//viewport code modeled after http://stackoverflow.com/a/17142856/2245528
private RectF GetViewport() {
    RectF viewport = new RectF();

    viewportMatrix.mapRect(viewport, originalViewport);

    return viewport;
}

private void Translate(float x, float y) {
    translationMatrix.postTranslate(x, y);

    invalidate();
}

private void Scale(float scaleFactor, PointF focusPoint) {
    if (focusPoint == null) {
        translationMatrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    }
    //keep the focus point in focus if possible
    else {
        translationMatrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, focusPoint.x, focusPoint.y);
    }

    invalidate();
}

private final Matrix translationMatrix = new Matrix();
private final RectF originalViewport = new RectF();
private final Matrix viewportMatrix = new Matrix();
```

`originalViewport` is set to `0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()`. `Translate` and `Scale` are called from gesture event handlers, which are working correctly.

The part that confuses me is `viewportMatrix`. It doesn't seem to matter whether I do

```
viewportMatrix.set(canvas.getMatrix());
```

or

```
viewportMatrix.preConcat(canvas.getMatrix());
```

or even a one-time call to

```
viewportMatrix.set(canvas.getMatrix());
```

at the beginning followed by side-by-side `Translate`/`Scale` calls to the two matrixes. I've even tried completely ignoring the `Canvas`'s built-in `Matrix` and rewriting `GetViewport` as

```
//viewport code modeled after http://stackoverflow.com/a/17142856/2245528
private RectF GetViewport() {
    RectF viewport = new RectF();

    translationMatrix.mapRect(viewport, originalViewport);

    return viewport;
}
```

I can never seem to match `getClipBounds()`, and the discrepancies are fairly serious:

with `viewportMatrix.set(canvas.getMatrix)`:

> clipBounds: Rect(-97, -97 - 602, 452) (699, 549)
>   viewport: RectF(97.04178, 97.06036, 797.04175, 647.06036) (700.0, 550.0)

with `viewportMatrix.preConcat(canvas.getMatrix)`:

> clipBounds: Rect(-97, -96 - 602, 453) (699, 549)
>   viewport: RectF(2708.9663, 2722.2754, 3408.9663, 3272.2754) (700.0, 550.0)

with `translationMatrix.mapRect`:

> clipBounds: Rect(-96, -96 - 603, 453) (699, 549)
>   viewport: RectF(96.73213, 96.85794, 796.7321, 646.8579) (700.0, 550.0)

with a one-shot call to `viewportMatrix.preConcat(canvas.getMatrix())` followed by side-by-side `Translate`/`Scale` calls:

> clipBounds: Rect(-96, -97 - 603, 452) (699, 549)
>   viewport: RectF(96.57738, 97.78168, 796.5774, 647.7817) (700.0, 550.0)

with a one-shot call to `viewportMatrix.set(canvas.getMatrix())` followed by side-by-side `Translate`/`Scale` calls:

> clipBounds: Rect(-96, -96 - 603, 453) (699, 549)
>   viewport: RectF(96.40051, 96.88153, 796.4005, 646.88153) (700.0, 550.0)

I can't even check [the `Canvas` source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/graphics/Canvas.java#Canvas), as all the `Matrix` code vanishes into private native calls whose code isn't shown.

Why are my `GetViewport` calls so grossly off, and what's going on behind-the-scenes with `getClipBounds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read through [this answer on GameDev SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120676/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-map-the-mouse-position-on-the-screen-so-that-collision-det/120678#120678), which uses matrix inversion to swap between screen and world coordinate systems:

> To go from screen to world space simply use Vector2.Transform. This is commonly used to get the location of the mouse in the world for object picking.
>
> ```
> Vector2.Transform(mouseLocation, Matrix.Invert(Camera.TransformMatrix));
> ```
>
> To go from world to screen space simply do the opposite.
>
> ```
> Vector2.Transform(mouseLocation, Camera.TransformMatrix);
> ```

Inspired by this approach, I tried inverting the transformation matrix like this:

```
private RectF GetViewport() {
    RectF viewport = new RectF();
    Matrix viewportMatrix = new Matrix();

    translationMatrix.invert(viewportMatrix);

    viewportMatrix.mapRect(viewport, originalViewport);

    return viewport;
}
```

This viewport correctly matches the results returned by `getClipBounds`.

[This matrix tutorial](http://www.3dgep.com/understanding-the-view-matrix/) explains what I'd noticed from the results of `transform` calls, but hadn't applied to my matrix:

> In a computer program the camera doesn’t move at all and in actuality, the world is just moving in the opposite **direction and orientation** of how you would want the camera to move in reality.
>
> In order to understand this correctly, we must think in terms of two different things:
>
> 1. **The Camera Transformation Matrix**: The transformation that places the camera in the correct position and orientation in world space (this is the transformation that you would apply to a 3D model of the camera if you wanted to represent it in the scene).
> 2. **The View Matrix**: This matrix will transform vertices from world-space to view-space.  *This matrix is the inverse of the camera’s transformation matrix described above.*